# Coby NBPC724B how to access BIOS?

Tags: laptop, android

My Coby NBPC724B, running Android 2.2 is having problems getting out of the Coby splash screen. I was wondering, what the key combination is that will allow me to boot into the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Coby does not seem to offer a manual for this product on their website however might of included one in the box. If you can manage to recover the manual I would recommend looking through it and trying to find your answer there. If not try calling Coby at

- US: 877-302-2629 (Monday-Friday 9AM-9PM EST)
- Canadian: 855-542-8917 (Monday-Friday 8AM-8PM EST)
- Germany: +49 (0) 800-10 10 345
- Austria: +43 (0) 800-02 25 62
- Switzerland: +41 (0) 800-00 16 22

Since this product does not seem to be available in the US (given it's not listed on the US website) I included extract contact numbers. If you need any more feel free to comment and I will try to find the one that's right for you.

Comment: Okay Griffin thanks for your reply i will try to find that manual

Comment: @MiniCookie You're good with the phone number?

Comment: Nope can't find the one related to my country.Portugal

Comment: @MiniCookie Just as a follow up were you ever successful in fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue. Apparently it is quite a common one. I managed to solve it after reading the contents of the following links:

http://browse.feedreader.com/c/TechKnow/542108907

http://foro.airis.es/t99-manual-reinstalacion-o-actualizacion-de-android-paso-a-paso

Good luck !

Comment: Please don't just link. Include the relevant information from the link. If the site ever goes down, your answer is useless. Read [answer].